# draw multiple images on android

Tags: android

I trying to make a manga reader app, I need to paint manga pages (as image) with vertical orientation on screen. I don't want to use webview as an image viewer. I will add zoom in out and drag to move later. But, now I need help about painting part.

There are the best way to do this? I'm trying extends View class and draw image in onDraw? Is this a good way? An example code will a big help.

Answer (score 1):

Since you need to add pages as images on one screen, i.e. , multiple images on a screen, I guess the following should be a good example for you to work on.

```
public class MyDrawableView extends View {
private Drawable mD1;
private Drawable mD2;

public MyDrawableView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    Resources res = context.getResources();
    mD1 = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.page1);
    //Set page1 bounds using : mD1.setBounds(x, y, x + width, y + height);

    mD2 = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.page2);
    //Set page2 bounds using : mD2.setBounds(a, b, a + width, b + height);
}

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    mD1.draw(canvas);
    mD2.draw(canvas);
}
}
```